# Ruby: string can't be coerced into fixnum

Tags: ruby

I created a program that accepts input for student name and scores for each student.  The names of the students are then saved as a csv file and so are the scores in a separate csv file.

Next I have a program that reads from that csv file and stores the names and scores back into an array. I then search for the student in the array and if found it displays the student and student score.

Here is where I am having an issue.  I want to find the sum of the scores array so i can then use the sum to find the average.  I tried doing this and got the error (see title):

```
score.inject(0) {|sum,i| sum += i}
puts sum
```

when I do a puts score it says this:
["100"
 "100"
 "98"
 "87"]

Is it saying that my scores are being read as strings because of the quotes around the numbers? and if so, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Just do

```
score.inject(0) {|sum,i| sum += i.to_i }
```

Your `score` array is `["100", "100", "98", "87"]`. In the array all elements are `String` objects, and you need to convert them to `Fixnum` objects. To do so, you need to use the method [`String#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) .

```
>> score = ["100", "100", "98", "87"]
=> ["100", "100", "98", "87"]
>> score.inject(0) {|sum,i| sum += i.to_i }
=> 385
>> score.map(&:to_i).inject(:+) # another way to do this
=> 385
```

Comment: 0 can be left out with the last one: `score.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)` (I prefer the name 'reduce' over 'inject' but they're the same).

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers You are right. But initialization, is not a bad idea. Initializing with `0` is not needed although.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Okay so here is what I put:
score.inject(0) {|sum,i| p sum += i.to_i }

and it returns back to me 0's. I did a test where I made an array of scores like you did above and it worked fine and gave me the sum but for some reason when im doing it in my program it returns zeros.

Can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong? Greatly appreciated.  Here is part of my code:

    <code>#Test to see what is in score array
puts score # ["100","100","98","87"] 

#Turn number strings to integers and print out the sum
score.inject(0) {|sum,i| p sum += i.to_i } # 0 0 0 0